# How to deal with scope-natured services like transactions in a DI and IOC environment

Tags: c#, transactions, dependency-injection, scope, ioc-container

Suppose that your code is properly designed for DI and IOC through constructor injection of any dependencies. Then whether an IOC container or DI-by-hand is used or not at the composition root doesn't matter much for this problem. I think.

Anyway, I find myself over and over again in a mental struggle with how I should best deal with scope-based services, like transactions or other obviously transient operations. There are constraints that I want to abide to:

- Don't let dependency interfaces be `IDisposable` - it's a leaky abstraction that only the actual implementing type (and the fiddler sitting at the composition root) should care about.
- Don't use static service locator types deep down the graph to resolve a dependency - only inject and resolve through the constructor.
- Don't pass the IOC container, if any, as a dependency down the graph.

To be able to use `using`, we need `IDisposable`, but since a dependency interface shouldn't be `IDisposable`, how do you get around it to get scoped behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases like this I would inject a service factory that creates those scoped services and let the service interface derive from `IDisposable`. This way the factory would be responsible to create the appropriate service instances and the only point that decides which service implementation to return. You would not need to inject the scoped service anywhere.

```
public interface ITransaction : IDisposable
{
}

public interface ITransactionFactory 
{
    ITransaction CreateTransaction();
}

public class Foo
{
    private readonly ITransactionFactory transactionFactory;

    public Foo(ITransactionFactory transactionFactory)
    {
        this.transactionFactory = transactionFactory;            
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithinTransaction()
    {
        using(ITransaction transaction = this.transactionFactory.CreateTransaction())
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually pretty neat, isn't it... `DoSomething` need not even be aware that it's in a transaction.

Comment: I completely agree with Florian here. In DI the consumer of a dependency shouldn't have to worry about the lifetime of a dependency. If it should worry, it's almost certainly a leaky abstraction and it shouldn't be a injected service. In Florian's example you see that the `ITransactionFactory` is the service and `ITransaction` just is the product of this service. This communicates clearly the lifetime of the `ITransaction`.

Answer (score 2):

Most IoC containers today have substantial built-in support for units of work of this nature.

In Autofac, the mechanism that best fits your requirements is the `Owned<T>` relationship type. You can see it in action (and get some more material) via [this article](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/).

Hope this helps,

Nick

Comment: Thanks, I actually read that article a couple of days ago :-). For the general, container-agnostic case, what's your view on the suggestion from Florian in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866983/how-to-deal-with-scope-natured-services-like-transactions-in-a-di-and-ioc-environ/5867076#5867076?

Comment: I noticed that your example `using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())` is very similar to Florian's suggestion, but you take a dependency on the container, as it seems.

Comment: The difference between these approaches is largely how other per-transaction dependencies will be scoped. In Florian's example, transaction lifetime is handled, but if we want actual components to have a lifetime corresponding to a transaction (e.g. data contexts) then we need to enlist the container's help. There's not usually such thing as container-agnostic lifetime handling, because there's a lot of variability between containers in how lifetime is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Roll your own "garbage collector" maybe? Something that periodically checks IsComplete and/or an LastAccessed attribute of a `Dictionary<Transaction>` and wastes the "old" ones. It's "a walking memory leak" but either you clean-up explicitly (like through IDisposable) or you workout how to clean-up automatically.

There may be an AOP solution to kicking-off the "gc"... a commit/rollback sounds like a good place to cut... and maybe you won't even need a GC at all... just cleanup the transaction on the way back-up the callstack from commit or rollback.

Good luck with it. I'll be interested to see what solutions (and ideas) other people come-up with.

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 1):

I guess another alternative you could use is to wrap your instances with a disposable type, that way it could automatically handle the disposal of the type regardless of whether the type is actually disposable. E.g, I could define something like:

```
public class DisposableWrapper<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly T _instance;
    private readonly IDisposable _disposable;

    public DisposableWrapper(T instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
        _disposable = instance as IDisposable;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposable != null)
            _disposable.Dispose();
    }

    public static implicit operator T(DisposableWrapper<T> disposableWrapper)
    {
        return disposableWrapper._instance;
    }
}
```

(Hopefully with a bit more error handling!)

Given that I know at the point of disposal whether the type is disposable, I can call it accordingly. I can also provide an implicit operator to cast back to the inner type from it. With the above, and a nifty extension method:

```
public static class DisposableExtensions
{
    public static DisposableWrapper<T> Wrap<T>(this T instance)
    {
        return new DisposableWrapper<T>(instance);
    }
}
```

Let's imagine that I have a service I am injecting into a type, it could be:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    IUser GetUser();
}
```

I could potentially do something like:

```
public HomeController(IUserService service)
{
    using (var disposable = service.Wrap())
    {
        var user = service.GetUser();

        // I can even grab it again, implicitly.
        IUserService service2 = disposable;
    }
}
```

Now regardless of whether that concrete implementation of `IUserService` is disposable or not, I can still safely work on the assumption that it doesn't matter.

Another quick console example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var instance = new ClassA().Wrap())
        {
            ClassA instanceA = instance;
        }

        using (var instance = new ClassB().Wrap())
        {
            ClassB instanceB = instance;   
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ClassA
{

}

public class ClassB : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.Write("Disposed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like the `Owned<T>` of Autofac: http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/

Comment: This looks really neat, but the problem is that with your code you assume that you own the service instance and it is therefore OK to dispose it when you are done with it. In your example a single  `IUserService` implementation might be provided to various clients. In this case your implementation will dispose this single instance. Of course, if you know for sure that this is no problem your implementation will work fine, but in all other cases it will cause lots of trouble.

Comment: @Florian I totally agree, this espcially wouldn't work well in Singleton scenarios too. It would really depend on how the developer knows the code will behave.